# Use javascript to query additional Rails data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a Listing#index page, which display 50 listings. I would like to have a button "More" that trigger javascript to query my MySql database for additional listings, then append to existing 50 listings without refreshing the page.

How should I go about this? I am using Rails and jQuery. I know Rails but new to Javascript.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Pagination is your friend.  Google "pagination rails".  There are many options.

Comment: Thanks Marc. I can't use pagination in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this problem.

1 You may render a "...js.erb" template which will perform some jquery code with append method (http://api.jquery.com/append/) or other manipulation logic. Do not forget to set :remote attribute to your button. I think this method will be easiest for you.

For example:

in controller:

```
def get_posts
  @posts.all # or something you need
  render "_get_posts.js.erb"
end
```

_get_posts.js.erb:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  $('#posts').append("<%= post.title %>");
<% end %>
```

Also in js.erb you may render partial or do something you want.

2 Bind logic to click event of your button (http://api.jquery.com/click/), than send ajax query to server with a variety of ways (http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/), than render data you have chosen (json, html, xml) and on client-side in callback function of ajax catch it and append to your page.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed advice. I am so new to Javascript that I still struggle with second step. Could you please give a very quick example how I should do it?